# Convert TXTto CSV

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, text, txt

I'm working on a project where I need to take a text file and make it an excel file. So far what I've come up with is this.

```
cls

Remove-Item -path D:\Users\zabin\OneDrive\Desktop\ITS3410\WEEK8\MainWarehouse.csv

Add-Content -path D:\Users\zabin\OneDrive\Desktop\ITS3410\WEEK8\MainWarehouse.csv -Value '"Part_Number","Cost","Price"'

$csvPath = 'D:\Users\zabin\OneDrive\Desktop\ITS3410\WEEK8\MainWarehouse.csv'


#region Excel Test
If (test-path HKLM:SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.Application) {
    Write-host "Microsoft Excel installed"
} else {
    Write-host "Microsoft Excel not installed"
}
#endregion

#region Patterns
$mainpattern1 = '(?<Partnumber>\d*\s*\w*,)(?<Cost>\d*.\d*),(?<Price>\d*.\d*)'
$mainpattern2 = '(?<Part_number>\d*-\d*-\d*),(?<Cost>\d*.\d*),(?<Price>\d*.\d*)'

#endregion

get-Content 'D:\Users\zabin\OneDrive\Desktop\ITS3410\WEEK8\MainWarehouse.csv' | #grabs the content
    Select-String -Pattern $mainpattern1, $mainpattern2 | #selects the patterns
    Foreach-Object {
        $Part_Number, $Cost, $Price = $_.Matches[0].Groups['Part_number', 'Cost','Price']



        [PSCustomObject] @{
     
     part_number = $Part_Number
     Cost = $Cost
     Price = $Price

   
    }
    $objResults | Export-Csv -Path $csvPath -NoTypeInformation -Append
    
}
```

some sample data is here

```
00001143 SP,136.41,227.35
00001223 SP,48.66,81.10
00001236 SP,149.72,249.53
0001-0003-00,100.95,168.25
00015172 W,85.32,142.20
```

I'm getting the file created and the header values are correct but I'm not sure how to get the values to import.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you testing for `Word.Application` if you want to find out if Excel is installed?

Comment: you can use `Import-Csv` on that sample data. give it the 3 column headers in the `-Header` parameter and it will import smoothly. then you can re-export it with proper a header line. if you MUST have it in excel format [ick [*grin*]], you can use the `ImportExcel` module to bot read & write excel files.

Comment: You are overcomplicating this. This is a very common thing to do, with plenty of samples/examples, in blogs, articles [(all over the web)](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell+convert+csv+to+xls%27&t=h_&ia=web), and [Youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+excel), and even modules, as Lee-Daily is pointing to for this.

Comment: @filburt That was my bad thank you for point ing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment... with the resources and a simple example.

```
Find-Module -Name '*excel*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Version     Name            Repository Description                
-------     ----            ---------- -----------                
7.1.1       ImportExcel     PSGallery  PowerShell module to import/export Excel spreadsheets, without Excel....                  
0.1.12      PSWriteExcel    PSGallery  Little project to create Excel files without Microsoft Excel being installed.             
1.0.2       PSExcel         PSGallery  Work with Excel without installing Excel        
...    
0.6.9       ExcelPSLib      PSGallery  Allow simple creation and manipulation of XLSX file                  
2.1         Read-ExcelFile  PSGallery  PowerShell module to import Excel spreadsheets, without Excel....    
...
#>
```

MSExcel will read properly formatted CSV's natively. So, to convert to a true XLS file, use PowerShell, MSOffice COM to open MSExcel with the CSV file, then save it as an XLS format.

```
$FileName = "$env:temp\Report"

Get-Process | 
Export-Csv -UseCulture -Path "$FileName.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

$excel         = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$excel.Visible = $true
$excel.Workbooks.Open("$FileName.csv").SaveAs("$FileName.xlsx",51)
$excel.Quit()

explorer.exe "/Select,$FileName.xlsx"
```

Your use case is of course as noted:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\temp\book1.txt' -header Title, Author
```

Then using COM as noted above.

Comment: I ended up solving this after I asked the question I had alot of flaws in this code

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this after I asked the question I had alot of flaws in this code

```
Add-Content -path D:\Users\zabin\OneDrive\Desktop\ITS3410\WEEK8\MainWarehouse.csv -Value '"Part_Number","Cost","Price"'

$csvPath = 'D:\Users\zabin\OneDrive\Desktop\ITS3410\WEEK8\MainWarehouse.csv'


#region Excel Test
If (test-path HKLM:SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Application) {#these next few lines will check if excel is installed on the system
    Write-host "Microsoft Excel installed"
} else {
    Write-host "Microsoft Excel not installed"
}
#endregion

#region Patterns
$mainpattern1 = '(?<Part_number>\d*\s*\w*),(?<Cost>\d*.\d*),(?<Price>\d*.\d*)'#These two line will use REGEX to help seperate the data
$mainpattern2 = '(?<Part_number>\d*-\d*-\d*),(?<Cost>\d*.\d*),(?<Price>\d*.\d*)'

#endregion

get-Content 'D:\Users\zabin\OneDrive\Desktop\ITS3410\WEEK8\Main.rtf' | #grabs the content
    Select-String -Pattern $mainpattern2, $mainpattern1 | #selects the patterns
   Foreach-Object {
        $Part_number, $Cost, $Price = $_.Matches[0].Groups['Part_number', 'Cost','Price']     #Gets the groups of a call to select-string



  $results = [PSCustomObject] @{#the list here is what i use to seperate the data onto the CSV file
     part_number = $Part_Number
     Cost = $Cost
     Price = $Price

   
    }
    
$results | Export-Csv -Path $csvPath -NoTypeInformation -Append #moves the results to the CSV file
    
}
```

Comment: Understood, and well, what you have here is a choice ***(options are always welcomed to all, as you'd never know)*** and does avoid the need to have MSExcel on the system, but if MSExcel is there, may as well use it.  *** ;-} ***, juusst, say'in.   *** ;-} ** Well, that or one of the available Excel modules. BTW, you will hear folks say, RegEx is really not the way to deal with XML. PowerShell has XML cmdlets for that purpose. `Get-Command -Name '*XML*' | Format-Table -AutoSize`